# Python Zeep - Multiple WSDL Files

Tags: python, python-3.x, zeep

I have two separate WSDL files that are provided to me to interact with a service, one WSDL file just provides a method to login and generate an access token.  The other WSDL file provides the methods to actually interact with the system.

If I instantiate the zeep SOAP client with the first WSDL file to login do I need to reinstantiate the client for the next WSDL file or can I simply tell it to go look at the next WSDL file?

```
from zeep import Client

client = Client("https://url.service.com/Session?wsdl")
token = client.service.login(username, password)

client = Client("https://url.service.com/Object?wsdl")
client.service.find(token, 'filter')
```

I attempted to use create_service but I don't think I'm using it correctly.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reinstantiate the second Client.

I expect that you also need to extend your code to use the same requests Session and Zeeps Transport.

```
from requests import Session
from zeep import Client
from zeep.transports import Transport

transport = Transport(session=Session())

client = Client("https://url.service.com/Session?wsdl", transport=transport)
token = client.service.login(username, password)

client = Client("https://url.service.com/Object?wsdl", transport=transport)
client.service.find(token, 'filter')
```

Comment: I think at this point that's the answer (and it's what I've been doing).  In my particular case I haven't had to make use of sessions because I pass the token back to the web service on each call.  I'll edit the answer to reflect this.